# How to get the foreign key value into href attribute of a hyperlink element as a url parameter in Django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have data table showing list of vehicles from the Vehicle model with Driver column. When user clicking on the Driver column value, I want to redirect the user to **driver detail** page url `driver-detail/license_number`.
I tried to pass the license_number to `href` attribute of hyperlink element like `href="{% url 'driver-detail' vehicle.driver.license_number %}"`. This does not help me, it's always empty. If I omit the `license_number` in the `href` value it will pass the `__str__(self)` return value of the Driver model, which is combination of `license_number` and `fullname`. If I change the return value of `__str__(self)` in the Driver model it will work. But I don't want to change the return value of `__str__(self)`.
Any help is much appreciated!

**Model.py**

```
class Driver(models.Model):
    license_number = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    license_issue_date = models.DateField("Issued Date")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.license_number + " " + self.fullname
   

class Vehicle(models.Model):
    license_plate = models.CharField(max_length=25, primary_key=True)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Vehicle model")    
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True, blank=True)
```

**template.html**

```
 <a href="{% url 'driver-detail' vehicle.driver.license_number %}" >
    {{vehicle.driver.license_number}}{{vehicle.driver.fullname}}
</a>
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('driver-detail/<str:pk>/', views.driverDetail, name='driver-detail'),
]
```

Comment: Your code look correct. Maybe try `vehicle.driver.pk`.

Comment: Pycm  `vehicle.driver.pk`  did not work

Comment: I guess it's because your mode2name conflict with field name. `Driver` with `driver `. So try renaming `Driver`like `Vehicle_Driver` or something like that. Or rename the field name to `vehicle_driver`. Then try `vehicle.driver.license_number `.

Comment: That shouldn't be possible. I am guessing that the page you render this in lists `Vehicle` objects? Given that you have `null=True` on the driver field its possible that a vehicle might not have a driver. I am guessing you're getting errors due to that. What if you surround that anchor in an [if template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/templates/builtins/#if)?

Comment: I changed the field name `driver`  in the `Vehicle` model to `vehicle_driver` fortunately it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's because your model name conflict with field name. `Driver` with `driver` . So try renaming Driver like `Vehicle_Driver` or something like that. Or rename the field name to `vehicle_driver` or something like that. . Then try `vehicle.field_name.license_number`.

Comment: That's not the issue. Python is case sensitive and Django also does not do anything such that you'd get arbitrary conflicts. The issue is probably something else.

Comment: Maybe, but he can try testing it.

Comment: AbdulAzizBarkat Really I'm not sure if that was the case, it worked after changing the field name into `vehicle_driver`.

Comment: @mebratu that's pretty weird, is it possible that you had another attribute / method called `driver` in the `Vehicle` model? The field name being `driver` and the model name being `Driver` wouldn't cause any issues at all.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat it was for that time being. Later it was same error. I do not what is going on. I managed the problem by passing the value by context.

Comment: @mebratu I guess the problem is probably due to the fact that it is possible for a vehicle object to not have a driver (You have `null=True` and `blank=True` on the field) as I mentioned in my comment on your question what happens if you wrap that HTML snippet in an if condition?

Comment: @mebratu { I managed the problem by passing the value by context.} what do you mean? You solved the problem by passing the value by context? Didn't you pass your object to views.py context before? Django is MVT system. Normally view and context is a must.

Comment: Did you get it to work or what? What was the problem? What was the solution?